# Check if URL contain the same string

Tags: php, css, url, prestashop, strpos

I'd like to turn on my class "selected" (which is a hover basically) when I'm on the corresponding category. Pretty much the active hover thing.

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
$url = $this->getLink($menu);
    $current_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $selected = (strpos($url, $current_url) !== false) ? true : false;
```

Thing is: it's working pretty well when the URL is like: http://my-website.com/en/15-this-categorie

But it does turn on every hover when the URL is: http://my-website.com/en/ where here, none of the hover are supposed to be turned on.

Need help here!

Comment: I don't know prestashop, but `15-this-categorie` should be linked to category ID that you should match instead of comparing full urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks for all your answers :D  
I solved this by comparing the id, this was actually the easiest way and the most logical one

```
    $url = '/'.$menu['item'].'-';
    $current_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $selected = (strpos($current_url, $url) !== false) ? true : false;
```

*$menu['item'] get the category id btw*

Comment: You don't have to go parsing request uri because everytime a category page is loaded you have a GET variable with `id_category`. So you can just do `$selected = Tools::getValue('id_category') == $menu['item'];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `$url` is the haystack.

So, since `/en/` is part of `$url` it will match.

You can either switch the variables up, or make an exception for `/en/`

so

```
$selected = (strpos($current_url, $url) !== false) ? true : false;
```

Or the way of the exception (This is just an example, don't blindly copy-paste it):

```
if($current_url == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/en'){
    $selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how could i make exeptions ?

Comment: @MartinFabre I've edited the answer with a way to use an exception, but since I can't test it on your application, you may need to modify it.

Comment: Is there any way i can do this with strpos ?

Comment: @MartinFabre yes, the strpos I've posted should work, I've inverted the variables, it now should only show selected if it's a full match.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in relation to a Category ID, tried this in smarty:

```
{if isset ($ page_name) && $ page_name = 'category' && $ smarty.get.id_category == 15}
```

Or in Php

```
if (Tools :: getValue ('id_category') == 15)
```

Regards